# Treating a mass term as an interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, feynman-diagrams, interactions, propagator

The mass term of, say, a one real scalar free quantum field theory can be treated as an interaction with $$\mathcal{L}_I= -\dfrac12 m^2 \phi^2.$$

Once that diagrams are summed to all orders of perturbation theory, we can get, out of the initial "free" propagator $\dfrac{i}{p^2+i\epsilon}$, the following propagator for the whole theory: $$\dfrac{i}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon},$$ once we realise that we have a geometric series in our hands.

However, how does the $1/2$ factor, appearing in all vertices because of $\mathcal{L}_I$, vanish? With $n$ vertices, this yields a $\left(\dfrac12\right)^n$ factor. We also get degenerate diagrams at every order in perturbation theory, but as far as I have tried, I have not been able to generically compensate the $1/2$ at every vertex.

Comment: The Feynman rule for $\frac12m^2\phi^2$ is just $im^2$, not $im^2/2$. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321099/84967

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks for your answer. I suspected the answer would lie in there, but to be honest I have trouble doing the calculation. Do you have a reference in mind that computes this explicitly?

Comment: You have two $\phi$'s, so  in a Wick contraction you can use *either* of them --  so you get a factor of two. This is just like the derivative of $(1/2) x^2$ being $x$ and not $2x$.